# Windows 7 | Microsoft SharePoint has stopped working | WerFault.exe Related to this message

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, sharepoint

I am in windows 7 - SP1 - Updated till may 2021.(PC)
Eset smart security with full license for 1 year has installed.
Some days ago when i started my windows after complete loading i faced this error message :

> Microsoft SharePoint has stopped working

[image]

When i go to task manager and check this message by going to it's process i jump to this file :

> WerFault.exe
> Location of file = C:\Windows\SysWOW64

Is my windows infected by a virus?
I had installed microsoft office after installing windows.
I double checked my office 2019 and figured out i did n't install SharePoint at all.
What is that message and how can i prevent it after loading windows?

---

**EDIT :**
I noticed there is a **Microsoft.SharePoint.exe** file in this path :

> C:\Users\My_Name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\21.205.1003.0003

But OneDrive is not active in startup of windows.
How can i disable it without uninstall in windows 7?
I could n't find any service for OneDrive!!!

Comment: Related to [WerFault.exe File](https://hp.teveotecno.com.ar/how-to-fix-the-werfault-exe-error-in-windows-10/)

Comment: What is the reason for DownVote? What did i do wrong?

Comment: Who DownVoted me? And why?

Comment: Who is DownVoting me without any reason?

Comment: Have you installed PowerShell v3? SharePoint is a .NET 3.0 product and can’t deal with .NET 4 that is installed by it.

Comment: My PowerShell version is 2.0 (Default of windows 7) - But i installed .net framework 4.8 - Because of i am asp.net web developer and i am working with this .net in visual studio.

Comment: Try to uninstall. Net 4 and see if it helps.

Comment: I checked .Net 3.5 using with visual studio - It is working and there is no problem about it.

Comment: @harrymc  Thanks for helping me - I did n't install SharePoint on my pc - So where does that error come from?

Comment: You mean that SharePoint isn't installed but is still faulting?

Comment: @harrymc Yes. This is why i asked this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible cause for this error message is by an Outlook add-in.

Here is how to disable it:

- Go to Outlook *File > Options > Add-ins*
- Choose "COM Add-ins" in the drop-down box at the bottom
- Click the "Go..." button
- In the "COM Add-ins" dialog, uncheck
  "Microsoft SharePoint Server Colleague Import Addin"
- Click OK.

If you don't need OneDrive, you could also uninstall it.

Comment: You are the best | I hate DownVoters by the way. I did n't do anything wrong here.

Comment: Senseless downvoting is a plague on our site. I did my share with +1 to your post, so all in all, you're still ahead, mathematically speaking.